# plane calculation in point cloud with lm() in R

Tags: r, lm, plane

I have some 3D points and I want to have the better plane which minimize the distance between the plane and the point cloud. I used `lm()` to extract the 3 values I need.

```
x<-sample(1:100, 100)
y<-sample(1:100, 100)
z<-sample(1:100, 100)
plot3d(x, y, z, type = "s", col = "red", size = 1)
my.lm <- #I tried different combination of lm: lm(x ~ y + z)/lm(y ~ x + z)/lm(z ~ y + x)
#lm fct     Intercept   1st after ~   2nd after ~
#lm(x~y+z) 43.45653      0.17151     -0.03203 
#lm(y~x+z) 40.66175      0.17159      0.02322
#lm(z~x+y) 50.95859     -0.03298      0.02390
planes3d(-1, 0.17151, -0.03203, 43.45653, alpha=0.5) #function use a b c and d of the ax+by+cz+d=0 equation
planes3d(0.17159, -1, 0.02322, 40.66175, alpha=0.5)
planes3d(-0.03298, 0.02390, -1, 50.95859, alpha=0.5)
```

I thought that the 3 planes extracted from the 3 lm() would be the same but they are very different. So I think that the reference axis chosen in the lm() function define the priority of research.
So how can I have the better plane which fit with my point cloud and that independantly (I don't want to affect the output when I choose which axis I put before the ~)
Where am I wrong? How can it be independant?

When I apply my algorithm with `lm(x~y+z)` I see that the plane is sometimes orthogonal compared to what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is correct, but maybe the question that you are trying to solve is not clear in the sense of the output that you expect.

In the example of a cloud of homogeneously distributed unlabelled 3D points, there is no unique way to perform a dichotomy, separating the points with a unique, "ideal" surface. You can do this for the individual Cartesian components of the set of points though, and this is what your code achieves.

The first plane, shown in red color in the panel on the left in the figure below, separates the points in a linearly optimal way by a plane that only considers the x-coordinate of the points as a function of their position, leading to a function of the type `x=f(y,z)`.

The second plane (green, on the right) is the result of a linear fit of the y-component of the points, `y=g(x,z)`; and the third (shown in blue, in the middle) is a linear fit of the z-component of the points in the set `z=h(x,y)`.

The three planes are certainly different, because they represent fits to different values. Hence, I don't think that there is anything wrong with your code and with your result.

[image]

Unlike the case described here, it is often possible to define meaningful (hyper-)planes separating different types of points, (like points with a certain value, e.g., temperature; or points with different attributes like "yellow" and "purple" points). It then depends on the distribution of these points in space whether they are linearly separable or not. In the latter case there are often solutions, too, but they are more complicated. For more information on such cases you may want to read about Support Vector Machines (SVM). Several R packages provide algorithms for SVMs such as, e.g., [`e1071`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html) or the popular [`caret`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) library.

Comment: If I understood well: SVM classify data, so the algorithm will search a plane which will separate my data into two separated groups with the maximization of the distance, no? But I'm looking for having the plane which fit my data and minimize the distance between the point cloud and the plane. I think I should use [this kind of method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares), but the `nls()` method in R is similar with `lm()`: I choose an order before/after '~' and I don't know what I should choose and whether I can use it to construct the plane like the output of `lm()`.